# Why is the POP3 protocol still in use?

Tags: email, imap, protocols, pop3

I am still trying to understand e-mail protocols. It seems that IMAP is more powerful than POP3. Why, then, does the POP3 protocol survive? It is still supported by popular email services like GMail.

Answer (score 11):

Because POP3 does not need as much storage on the server side. And because it is more simple and easy to implement.

Comment: Why would POP3 need less storage on the server side? You have the option not to delete mails from the server using POP3 to receive them, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

I think part of it is that IMAP is usually used in scenarios where the emails are retained on the server, whereas POP is used almost exclusively for situations where the email is downloaded to the local machine, which is what most ISPs providing email facilities for their customers want you to do (and also what most of the customers probably want as well, although less so as they get more exposure to the Internet and things like gmail and yahoo, etc.)

Another reason it is probably preferred by email providers is that it does polling, much like an RSS news reader.  The POP client will open a TCP/IP connection to the server, authenticate itself, ask for any email and do whatever processing it needs, and then close the connection.

IMAP clients generally keep one or more TCP/IP sockets open with the server the whole time they are running, taking up those resources.  Yet another reason for ISPs to prefer POP.

Google mail supports both POP and IMAP protocols.

(P.S. I do not mean to sound like I am having a go at ISPs.  I think the reasons I've attributed to them above are very pragmatic and sensible.)

Answer (score 6):

A few reasons:

1. POP3 does need far less server side
   storage.
2. POP3 is much easier to implement.
3. POP3 is private by default (it
   assumes that you want to delete
   email off the server after
   downloading it).
4. Initially almost all ISPs had tiny
   storage limits (since their are free
   large storage email services this
   matters less now) so deleting emails
   that you downloaded was a must.
5. (for completeness - thanks Evan) POP
   clients open a TCP/IP connection to
   the server, authenticates itself,
   asks for any email and does whatever
   processing it needs, and then close
   the connection. IMAP clients
   generally keep one or more TCP/IP
   sockets open with the server the
   whole time they are running, taking
   up those resources.
6. POP is a much simpler protocol to implement and can handle a greater number of clients with the same amount of resources.

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo mail still does not offer IMAP. My guess is that it's because I'm more likely to use their site than Outlook, meaning I'll have to see their ads.

Comment: It's Yahoo who's not good at knowing user wants. Gmail users do have POP3 and IMAP but they do use Gmail instead because it's remote and equally fast as Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Many email services (such as those provided by ISPs) only offer a limited size mailbox. This makes it necessary to download your messages to your computer to be able to store the large number of emails that are common these days.

Comment: And this makes POP3 necessary? If you couldn't download messages with IMAP, it would be of very little value.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is POP3 fetchers. You may have a central IMAP mailbox where you want to download mail from all other accounts of yours to keep all your mail in same place. This is usually done with POP3 fetchers which poll your other mailboxes periodically and load mail from there in your primary mailbox.

Although IMAP fetchers do exist, most of fetchers are still POP3-only and if your other mailbox does not support POP3, you may have troubles using a fetcher to link it with your primary mailbox.